# Confusion in conversion of array to json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array $arr_name which prints out

```
  {"name" => "tom", "age" => 10}, {"name" => "jack", "age" => 11}
```

how do i get it to print the desired output using php ?

```
Desired Output in JSON is as follows 
{
   "Students" : [  {"name" => "tom", "age" => 10}, {"name" => "jack", "age" => 11}
                ]
}
```

Sorry but i find this very very confusing and have spent the last 2 hrs trying to get "Students" key asssigned to have a value with the contents of $arr_name

Comment: i solved this by $json_response_arr=array("Students" => $arr_name); and then doing a echo json_encode($json_response_arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n\n";

Answer (score 1):

PHP already has a built in function to convert an array into JSON:

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: lmao...this is hilarious

Comment: I am using json_encode but the question is how to exactly store the values in the array to get output using json_encode.

Answer (score 1):

Here simple example given below like:

Put your array place of `$put_your_array` in loop:

```
        $output=array();            
        foreach ($put_your_array as $key => $value) {               
            $output['Students'][]=array(
                'name'=>$value['name'],
                'age'=>$value['age']
            );
        }            
        echo json_encode($output);
```

And get output would you seem like json format...

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do that, loop through the array then assign it to new array

Ex:

```
$new_array=array();
foreach(your array as $key => $val)
{
   $new_array['Students'][] = $val;
}

return json_encode($new_array);
```